# How does bash know about its parent's coprocess in this situation, and why does a shebang line change it?

Tags: bash, shebang, coprocesses

`outer.sh`:

```bash
ls -l /proc/$$/exe
coproc cat
./inner.sh
kill $!
```

`inner.sh`:

```bash
ls -l /proc/$$/exe
set | grep COPROC || echo No match found
coproc cat
kill $!
```

When I run `./outer.sh`, this gets printed:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 joe joe 0 Jun 16 22:47 /proc/147876/exe -> /bin/bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 joe joe 0 Jun 16 22:47 /proc/147879/exe -> /bin/bash
No match found
./inner.sh: line 3: warning: execute_coproc: coproc [147878:COPROC] still exists
```

Since `COPROC` and `COPROC_PID` aren't set in the child, how does it know about the one from the parent to be able to give me that warning?

Also, I discovered that if I add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of `inner.sh`, or if I call `bash ./inner.sh` instead of just `./inner.sh` from `outer.sh`, then the warning goes away. Why does this change anything, since it's getting ran with a bash subprocess either way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A script without shebang is meant to be interpreted by a POSIX-compliant `sh` interpreter. That's actually the POSIX way to write POSIX scripts, POSIX doesn't specify shebangs, though in practice using shebangs is more portable / reliable, and here is a good example why.

The bash shell is such a POSIX sh interpreter. bash (some versions and in some custom builds and in some environments) is actually the only FLOSS shell that I know that has been *certified* as compliant when running as `sh` (not when running as `bash`).

When executing a shebang-less script, bash, when `execve()` returns ENOEXEC and after having checked that it doesn't look like a binary file, interprets it in a child of his, simulating an execution by attempting to reset its state to the default.

That means however that that script when run from `bash` is interpreted as a bash script instead of a POSIX sh script unless `bash` is running in POSIX mode itself (such as when invoked as `sh` itself).

```
$ cat a
alias uname='echo hi'
uname
$ zsh -c ./a
hi
$ sh ./a
hi
$ bash -c ./a
Linux
$ (exec -a sh bash -c ./a)
hi
```

See how `a` was interpreted as `bash` language (ignoring aliases) instead of the sh languages when invoked by `bash`.

```
~$ strace -qqfe execve bash -c ./a
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "./a"], 0x7fff0081a820 /* 66 vars */) = 0
execve("./a", ["./a"], 0x55b18b3a4660 /* 66 vars */) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
[pid 123559] execve("/usr/bin/uname", ["uname"], 0x55b18b3a4660 /* 66 vars */) = 0
Linux
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=123559, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

See how `bash` didn't execute  `sh` to interpret the script.

The fact that you get that `warning: execute_coproc: coproc [147878:COPROC] still exists` is a bug whereby `bash` fails to reset its state properly.

In any case, `coproc` is not a `sh` keyword so doesn't have its place in a shebang-less script. `coproc` is from `zsh` (while coprocesses are from ksh), though `bash`'s implementation is completely different, so you should have a `#! /bin/bash -` shebang here.

With `bash ./inner.sh` or with a shebang, there is a proper execution of a new interpreter instance, and `execve()` completely and correctly wipes the process memory.

Comment: One thing I don't understand here: if executing a script with no shebang line means to run it as a POSIX script, then why does running `./a` print `Linux` instead of `hi`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, that's the whole point in my answer, `bash` is not POSIX compliant in that regard when not in POSIX mode. If your interactive shell is bash, bash will interpret it itself instead of invoking `sh` on it, and unless your `bash` was invoked as `sh` or with `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in the environment, it will interpret it in a non-POSIX way. In effect, the script will be interpreted as if it was written in the bash language instead of the `sh` language.